# Adding a table view to a UI View Controller error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a storyboard set up with a View controller . the view controller is divided into two halves , one half is a UI date picker and the other is a table view . When I set the view controller as the delegate and datasource , I get the following error

```
reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdb29b4d9e0'
```

My View controller is defined in the following way

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomViewController:  UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        return 3;
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        var sampleCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

        return sampleCell;

    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure if your view's class is your table's class? I got the same error when I forgot to set my view's class.

Comment: Glad I helped :) And thanks now I can comment everywhere haha :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an IBOutlet property that is connected to the UITableView in the storyboard/nib? Is the view controller set as the delegate and dataSource for the table view?

Comment: no IBOutlets defined in the storyboard . the view controller is set as the datasource and delegate , when I use the whole view controller as a storyboard it works fine, it fails when I divide the view controller like I mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an outlet for the UITableView and set the delegates:

Then in viewDidLoad set the tableView's datasource and delegate to self since the ViewController implements the protocol.